# Obtaining iPhone Latitude & Longitude

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, location

I've been attempting to retrieve a iPhone's latitude and longitude for purposes of passing to an external function in order to geotag something. However, I've been rather unsuccessful. Here is the code I'm working with right now.

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func findMyLocation (sender:AnyObject)
{
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if error == nil
        {
            println("Reverse geocoder failed with error " + error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0
        {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        }
        else
        {
            println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })
}

func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {
        //stop updating location to save battery life
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if (placemark.postalCode != nil)
    {
        println(placemark.postalCode)
        println("just tried to print placemark's postal code")
    }
        //println(placemark.locality ? placemark.locality : "")
        //println(placemark.postalCode ? placemark.postalCode : "")
        //println(placemark.administrativeArea ? placemark.administrativeArea : "")
        //println(placemark.country ? placemark.country : "")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)
{
    println("Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

As of now, I get pretty much nothing when I run the program. I have a little button that says "Find Me", and upon clicking, nothing pops up in the output box. I have the iOS Simulator's Debug location set to "Apple", and I've previously tried always enabling location services in settings on the simulator when trying to run the program (although currently it's not showing my app and the option to do so). 
I really just want to get a double value for latitude and longitude, and if there's a simple something that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should only request one type of authorization. Pick the one that makes the most sense for the user experience of your app.
2. You are probably missing your purpose string, which is now required to activate location services. Add one of the following keys to your Info.plist:

   - `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` - if requesting Always permission
   - `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` - if requesting WhenInUse permission

   The value of the key should be a string that explains why you want location permissions.

Comment: I'm very new to XCode - how exactly do I add one of those keys? What does it look like and where does it go?

Comment: There should be a folder called supporting files. In there there is a file called target-Info.plist, where target is the name of your project's application target. You add the key/value pair in that file. If you are new to Xcode I suggest you read some of the guides and tutorials to get the hang of it before asking for help. It is hard to help someone who doesn't understand the jargon.